# Are there fenders designed specifically for bikes with racks?

Tags: rack, weather, fenders, rain

I have a bike with a rear rack and want to buy a rear fender. Is there any fender that is specifically designed to be used in a combination with a bike rack?

Comment: Generally your regular full fenders can be mounted under the bike rack using the same set of eyelets or another set depending on the bike. Some rack manufacturers sell specific fenders which attach to their racks, but unlike full fenders, these won't protect your drivetrain from spray all that much.

Comment: is it okay to mention specific brands/models on StackExchange? I'd be curios to see some rack-specific fenders. In my understanding, a properly designed rack fender can be more stable and, hopefully, easier to install on a bike with an already installed rack.

Comment: Well, we don't do product rec here. I highly doubt its more stable (in fact, i'd be inclined to say less stable) than a proper regular fender. Installing fenders isn't so hard that I think ease of installation is a relatively moot point when the fenders are attached to the bike (versus clip on fenders).

Answer (score 5):

Fenders don't fall into an "ok with racks" or "not ok with racks" category. Generally speaking, most traditional fender designs will work on bikes with racks attached. There may be certain combinations of fenders and racks that are problematic, but those are the exception.

An example of a problem would be a bike whose rear rack is very close to the top of the rear wheel - it would be hard to fit a fender in there, but that's a specific problem which requires a specific solution.

That said, when putting a lot of accessories on a bike, we should expect to be bending and cutting and filing as we go. We should not expect a front/rear set of fenders and racks to be a perfect fit on a frame out of the box unless each of those parts were specifically designed to be a fit with each other.

Answer (score 3):

Most standards fenders will work with a rack.  You do have bikes designed for both - you will have two bosses.  You can double up and use the same boss for both but a separate is much preferred.

If a bike will take a rack then it will (almost always) take fenders.  But you can have a bike designed to take fenders but not a rack. People use fender mounts for a rack on bike not actually designed for a rack.

[Notice the two bosses on the rear of this bike](http://salsacycles.com/bikes/vaya/2016_vaya_x9)

Answer (score 1):

If its better integration of rack & fender you seek, look into getting a rack with a centerline stud or nut that you can attach the outmost half of the fender to.

See this [pic](https://www.flickr.com/photos/kaptainamerika/4463443539) for a rear fender+rack example.

Comment: now that I learned that there are no bike-specific fenders, this answers my next question! :) Thank you!